# magento.store_website' doesn't exist while installing magento 2

Tags: php, mysql, magento2

on Clean database i'm getting this kind of error while installing magento 2
[image]

how can i solve the prolem? or what possible ways is causing this kind of error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try following ways:

- First, try to uninstall Magento: `bin/magento setup:uninstall` and try install Magento again: `bin/magento setup:install`
- If uninstall doesn't work, try to remove env.php and run `bin/magento setup:install` again